# SQL Server Reporting Services SQL server 2005 publish a report via web service

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Imagine you have 2 applications Application A and Application B. 
Basically I would like to insert records that exist in Application A into Application B.
Sql Server Reporting Server is available on Application A

And I was wondering if it is possible to build a report that gathers the record that I need and then publish it as a web service so I can consume it on Application B and then do the inserts.

Application A and B are in two different web servers separated by the internet.

If this is possible could someone post a link that shows an example?

BTW: My experience with SSRS is null, but I have been a web developer for quite a while so I have a general understanding of what we could do I just need some one to point me into the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is not designed to serve data to other webservers, it is designed to nicely layout and display data from one or more SQL servers.

It seems you can connect SSRS to external SQL servers when you have [the right licensing](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34113603/2-database-servers-and-1-reporting-services.aspx). So if you want you application B to display data from both SQL servers you can use one SSRS report on computer B to display data from both.

However it seems you want to do inserts on computer B, using a report from computer A. I would not use a report for that, but a direct connection using ODBC, JDBC or another inter-database connection strategy - such as simply transferring plain-text files over FTP. The [BCP utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28SQL.80%29.aspx) is a power tool to output plain-text files from database queries. You could even run that directly from computer B, connecting to computer A.